# How to show multiline textbox which has text edit options (Bold, Italic, underling, font and colors options) as shown below on screenshot

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I am building react application where i want to allow user to add multiline comment and allow them to have different option like bold, italic, underline, font options and colour. just like normal texteditor option we get in different website.

Also once user apply this styles to text i want it to save in useState with those styles.

Below is screenshot what i am talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use third party plugin: [CkEdirto](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/react.html) check [reference](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/react.html)

Check API docs for more customization.

Comment: CKEdirot is opensource but we have to take licence for using CKEdirot into real word project. Do you know any other way or open source framework which will work without licence.

Comment: Yash, you can check this (10 Best And Open-source Rich Text Editors For React Applications) https://reactscript.com/best-rich-text-editor/